# Can any body tell me why the size of this structure is 16 on a 32 bit architecture?

Tags: c, struct

Why the size of this structure is 16 on a 32-bit architecture?

```
struct data {
    char x;
    long int y;
    char z;
    short int s;
    char l;
} data_1;
```

Comment: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119123/995714)

Answer (score 0):

On your architecture all objects of type `long int` must be at addresses that are 4-byte aligned, and `short int`s 2-aligned. Since the members must be laid out in memory in that order, there will be 3-byte padding after `x`; 1-byte padding after `z`, and 3 bytes after `l`. The members themselves require 9 bytes for char is 1 byte, short 2 and long 4; and 7 bytes were wasted for padding.

The size will drop to 12 bytes by simply placing `char x;` **after** `long int y;`. Then there will be only 3 bytes of padding, after `l`.